# remove active class on the next element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on this selection which adds active class, what I want is to remove the active class next to the selected element. If there's only one option left. ex. I got 5 options, then selected 1,2,3,4 if I select the fifth option the active class of the first option will be remove, then If I select again the 1 it will become active then, option 2 will become inactive.

Hope you help me. thanks.

```js
$('ul li a').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var len = $('ul .active').length;
    var arr = [];
    $('ul li a').each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            arr.push(i + 1);
            if (len > 4) {
                if (arr[arr.length - 1] == 5) {
                    $('ul li:nth-child(' + arr[0] + ') a').removeClass('active');
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
ul{
  padding: 0;
}
ul li{
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px  15px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
ul li a.active{
  background-color: green;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is working as you expected. What you exactly want?

Comment: @Laxminarayan sorry, ill update my question

Comment: Could I advice a simpler logic, just keep an MRU of the clicked items, and just splice.  Use the MRU to update your active class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Here it is.

```js
$('ul li a').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    
    if($(this).parent().next('li').length){
        $(this).parent().next().children().removeClass('active'); 
    }else{
  $(this).parent().parent().children().first().children().removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

```css
ul{
  padding: 0;
}
ul li{
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px  15px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
ul li a.active{
  background-color: green;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this, Check if next `li` exist and add logic

```js
$('ul li a:not("active")').click(function() {
    
    
    $(this).parent().next("li").find("a").removeClass("active");
           
    if ($(this).parent().next("li").length == 0)
    {
        $('ul li a').eq(0).removeClass("active");
    }
    
    $(this).addClass("active");
    
});
```

```css
ul{
  padding: 0;
}
ul li{
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px  15px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
ul li a.active{
  background-color: green;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hi sir, thanks for help your answer is correct, can you exclude clicking on active class. it will only work on inactive elements.

Comment: Yes, I've updated, you can easily do it with `a:not("active")`